# Postgresql: return show param list not found in base

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to verify if a list of entity id exist in base.
As such, I use the `IN` keyword to pass the list. This will help me to get the entity whose id equals one in the list.

But, I would like to write a request returning the id (from the list) which were not found in the base. My research and knowledge seem to say no about this question, but maybe I missed something.

Is it possible?

Have a good day

Comment: Please provide the schema, example input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a `left join`.  Here is an example:

```
select *
from (values (1), (2), (3)) v(id) left join
     t
     using (id)
```

Comment: Thanks ! Your comment gave me the solution. My description wasn't the best apparently, cause using the id will return all the entities in base, plus a "null" entity (this means that the fields from the entity will all be null except for the id). Using an other field to find the entity will result is the following solution `SELECT number
FROM (VALUES ('001'), ('002'), ('XXXXXXXXXXX')) v(number) LEFT JOIN customer USING (number) WHERE id IS NULL`